# Danamic Claims in IdentityServer

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

I'm looking at the [AspNetIdentity_2fa](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity_2fa) sample and trying to modify it to include some dynamic claims for users. Let's name it `calculated_value` claim which is created dynamically when a user is authenticated, and then is included in the user's claims list and passed with the the authentication token. I know I could create a separate Web API to get this value but since it is small data and that it is needed as soon as a user is authenticated, I thought I'd just pass it as claim. In the samples I see that claims always coming from static or hard-coded data. How can I create dynamic/late-bound claims?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago I spent some time on trying to integrate Identity Server v3 with Active Directory. I wanted to authenticate users via AD and to read "claims" from AD. To do so I provided a custom implementation of `IUserService`. It was more or less based on in memory implementation of these interface i.e. `InMemoryUserService`.

When your custom implementation is ready you have to register it. However, *AspNetIdentity_2fa* sample project already registers a custom implementation of `IUserService` i.e. `UserService` (just search a project for this class). It is derived from `AspNetIdentityUserService` which implements `IUserService`.

So, instead of providing completely new implementation try to modify it. I think that you should look at `AuthenticateLocalAsync`, `AuthenticateExternalAsync` and `GetProfileDataAsync` methods (see `InMemoryUserService` for reference) and override them. First 2 are used to authenticate users and the last one to read requested claims for users.

Comment: Great, your guidance lead me to the solution. I got this working by overriding `GetClaimsFromAccount`. Thank you!